# application assigns value to parameter in stored procedure, used in Crystal Report

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports, parameter-passing, crystal-reports-xi

I have a custom application that has an embedded Crystal Reports viewer. The RPT file in question calls a stored procedure. The stored procedure has a parameter, "**UserID**".

I want to configure the report so it can recieve a value for **UserID** from the application.

Right now, when I preview the report in CR11.5, it prompts me to enter a value for **UserID**. instead, I would like the custom application to do this for me so the **Enter Values** box does not appear when the report is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution. If the application is already rigged to pass a value to a specific parameter, all you have to do is create a parameter in the RPT file and give it the same name:

1. right-click **Parameter Fields** in the **Field Explorer**
2. new
3. name the parameter
4. click ok
5. the report should now run as you need it to in the test environment.